# What archival method (tar, zip, 7z, etc) allows me to retain folder modification dates on macOS?

Tags: tar, timestamps, zip, archive, 7z

I currently have a directory in a hard drive, say `TopFolder` which contains 3 subfolders, `Folder1`, `Folder2`, and `Folder3`.

When I am in the top level directory of the hard drive, and do:

```
tar cf TopFolder.tar Folder1 Folder2 Folder3
```

it creates a `tar` file that, when extracted, makes the modified dates of `Folder1`, `Folder2`, and `Folder3` equal to the time when they were extracted.

I noticed that `zip` doesn't have this issue and retains the modified dates of `Folder1`, `Folder2`, and `Folder3`. Generally, `zip` is slower due to compression. Is there a good method to archive folders if I need the modification dates to stay as-is, without relying on `zip`? Is there a method in 7z that is just as fast as `tar` without compression? Thanks!

My tar is bsdtar 3.3.2 on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it creates a tar file that, when extracted, makes the modified dates of Folder1, Folder2, and Folder3 equal to the time when they were extracted.

Your `tar` works in peculiar ways or maybe you've overlooking something (e.g. you immediately add new files to unpacked directories) because `tar` by default restores directories modification dates. I've just doubled checked it using tar version 1.32 in Fedora 32.

> Is there a method in 7z that is just as fast as tar without compression? Thanks!

You don't need 7z but you can always use the store compression method in 7z, e.g.

`7za a -mx=0 -ms=off -mhc=off archive.7z <files>`

Comment: You are right, I somehow was not using `GNU tar` but `bsdtar 3.3.2` on a Mac. Does `bsdtar` not support modification dates?

Comment: MacOS may automatically create/add additional system directories for each extracted directory which could be the real issue, e.g. `.DS_Store`

Comment: And many if not all zip programs support `-0` (zero) for create with no compression. I don't have Mac, but bsdtar on FreeBSD and (!) Windows 10 (which has several traditional Unixy tools such as curl and tar builtin, as well as the WSL option) both restore directory times for me.